# Grunt installation in mac os

Tags: node.js, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, yeoman

I want to create angular js app using bootstrap, for that I installed node.js pkg file in my mac.
Afterwards I installed yeoman (`$sudo npm install --global yo`). Documentation says if we install yo then we get grunt and bower automatically installed. In my case grunt and bower are not being installed.

So I decided to install it externally. I used following commands:

`$sudo npm install -g bower` => it works perfectly and giving me all files and packages.

`$ sudo npm install -g grunt` => it works perfectly but not giving me all files and packages

grunt are installed on path of `usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt`
grunt folder contains files

```
constributing.md
licenses-mit
readme
aaveyor.yml
internal-tasks
lib
node_modules
package.json
```

Which files I am missing?

If I run command `$ grunt --version` then I got following error

```
-bash: /grunt: No such file or directory
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to run:

```
$ npm install -g grunt-cli
```

The global binary command-line tool is `grunt-cli`, not `grunt`. It's a little bit confusing in the beginning, as `grunt-cli` provides a global binary which is callable by `grunt`.

So, in the end:

- Install `grunt` locally in your application.
- Install `grunt-cli` globally.

Then, you can run `grunt` from anywhere as expected :-)

Comment: Thanks dude. I got it now.